# How do I stop my cat from wall scratching when I sleep?

Tags: cats, scratching

A friend gave me her cat when he was 9 months old and he was very kind, loving,and gentle.  The first night I had him he jumped on my bed, laid next to my face, and wrapped his paw around me like he was trying to cuddle like a person does.  He did this for about a week until one night when I went to bed he started scratching the walls and has been doing it every single night when I go to bed.  He is going on to be 2 years old now and continues to do it every night for hours.  He has scratching posts, toys, food, is fixed, and receives plenty of attention and play.  I'm not sure why he started doing it or why he only does it when I try to sleep.  I don't think I have mice because there are no signs of any and I even placed traps just in case but still nothing.  Is there anything I can do to stop this because everywhere I look online has no answers.

Comment: How do you respond when he starts scratching the walls?